# Checking Differentiability Of g(x) Using Information Of f(x) (unsolved)

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Let $$f(x)=e^{x+1}-1, g(x)=p|f(x)|-\sum_{k=1}^n|f(x^k)|, n \in \mathbb N$$
> It is given that $g(x)$ is a differentiable function over the complete real numbers. If value of $p=100$, then sum of possible values of $n$ is $\dots$

I basically couldn't think of any way to start with this problem, Clearly $|f(x)|$ is not differentiable at $1$ point whereas in even powers ($f(x^{2n}))$ of $f(x)$, the function is differentiable at all points. Simply speaking, for odd values of $k$, function will not be differentiable but for even values of $k$, the function is differentiable at all points. But I have no clue on how to apply this concept in this question. The series is getting too long with none satisfactory results nor any hint for approaching this problem.

---

EDIT: Can somebody please elaborate Ashish Ahuja's answer more? For checking differentiability at $x=-1$ (as suggested by below answer), how can we proceed? I suppose we can calculate the answer ($n=19,20$) from here, but how? Also have a look at my answer below and kindly spot my mistake please. How can we confirm that the problem only occurs at $x=-1$ and not other numbers? 
Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

The function of the form

$$
k|e^{x+1} - 1| - |e^{x^k+1}-1|
$$

is differentiable at $x = -1$. Using this along with what you've already noted will allow you to arrive at the answer.

Comment: Thank You @AshishAhuja. It would be great if you elaborate some more :-) I am not able to carry forward it, sorry

Answer (score 1):

From what I have understood from the above answer, $g(x)$ is continuous at $x=-1$. So I separated $g(x)$ into two parts: $$x\gt -1,x\lt -1$$
For an odd number $k$, $$x\lt -1, f(x^k) \lt 0$$
$$x \gt -1, f(x^k) \gt 0$$
For an even number $l$, $$f(x^l)\gt 0 \space \space\space \forall x \in \mathbb R$$
$$
g(x)=
\begin{cases}
-100f(x)-\bigg(-f(x)+f(x^2)-f(x^3)+f(x^4)- \dots\bigg), & x \lt -1 \\
100f(x)-\bigg(f(x)+f(x^2)+f(x^3)+f(x^4)+ \dots\bigg), & x \gt -1
\end{cases}
$$
Now derivating $g(x)$ once,
$$
g'(x)=
\begin {cases}
-100f'(x)-\bigg(-f'(x)+2xf'(x^2)-3x^2f'(x^3)+4x^3f'(x^4)- \dots\bigg), & x \lt -1 \\
100f'(x)-\bigg(f'(x)+2xf'(x^2)+3x^2f'(x^3)+4x^3f'(x^4)+ \dots\bigg), & x \gt -1 \\
\end {cases}
$$
Now applying the condition, $g'((-1)^+)=g'((-1)^-)$, we get
$$1+3+5+ \dots n=100$$
But this gives $n=10$ which is not the correct answer. The correct answer is $$n=19,20$$
Can anyone please spot my mistake or any alternative method?

Comment: Your mistake is in the last step: For $r \in \mathbb{N}$,

$$1 + 3 + 5 + 7 + \cdots + (2r - 1) = r^2.$$

Comment: How would we account for $n=20$ @eeen?

Comment: Thanks for reading my answer :-)

Comment: The equation $g'((-1)^+) = g'((-1)^-)$ with $n = 19$ should be the same as that with $n = 20$ (look at the term $20x^{19}f'(x^{20})$).

Also, no problem! :)

Comment: Ummm sorry @eeen, I am not getting your point

Comment: What happens in the problem if $n = 20$? Try finding $g'(x)$ when $n = 20$, and then check the values of $g'((-1)^+)$ and $g'((-1)^-)$.

Comment: Cancels out? @eeen

Comment: I'm getting some issue in the simplification step $g'((-1)^+) = g'((-1)^-)$. I think the expressions for $g'$ are correct, but there seems to have been some error in the calculation of $g'((-1)^+)$ and $-$, which has led to the error. I'll see if I can write this up more clearly tomorrow, but for now I can confirm that everything before that is cent percent correct. I also think you've used the hint in the other answer already, since you recognized that the only problem is at $-1$. So checking those calculations (I think you'll have to split into $n$ odd and even cases) will do it.

Comment: Also, how are we assured that it will be differentiable at all other points except $-1$? @TeresaLisbon

Comment: Also @eeen, same doubt at $x=-1$ and other numbers?

Comment: @PCMSE If $h(x)$ is a differentiable function, then the only possible place where $h(x)$ can be non-differentiable (it may not necessarily be), is where $h(x) = 0$. This is because if you take the differential quotient at a point where $h$ is non-zero, then $h$ is continuous hence non-zero in a neighbourhood of such a point, so the modulus simplifies in that neighbourhood. So $g$ can only be non-differentiable at a point where one of the $f(x^k)$ equals zero i.e. where one of the $x^k$ equals $-1$. This can happen only if $x=-1$, no  other number raised to any power can give $-1$.